# Use Custom Table Cells Made in Interface Builder with three20

Tags: iphone, ios, three20, tableview

Is there a way to design a `UITableCell` in Interface Builder and use that in three20, with the `TTTableViewController`?

I can only find examples that programmatically create TTTableCell types.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, three20 doesn't have any kind of interface builder support (and nib files support).

All elements related to three20 have to be created and managed programmatically.